# Why can't openpyxl append list of tuples

Tags: excel, list, tuples, append, openpyxl

Edited for more detail:

Trying to append a list of tuples to bottom of an Excel range using "sheet.append() without using a for loop.  The list is shown in the code below.  I thought "append" could take a list of tuples and append each tuple to a new row without me using a for loop.

```
wb = wb = load_workbook(filename=fullPath)
sh = wb['Ledger']
p = [('MARVIN VILLA', '440.00'), ('ALVIN D GARCIA', '250.00'), ('ALEX JONES', '350.00')]
sh.append(p)
wb.save(fullPath)
wb.close()
```

this gives me an error:
Cannot convert ('MARVIN VILLA', '440.00') to Excel

Comment: This code is incomplete, please provide more context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's probably because [`append`](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.html) does not accept a list of *iterables* as an argument.

> `append` (*iterable*)
> Appends a group of values at the bottom of the current sheet.
>
> Parameters:   **iterable**(list|tuple|range|generator or dict)
> *– list, range or generator, or dict containing values to append*

You can try writing/appending each tuple separatly (*if this is the expected behaviour/output*) :

```
wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
sh = wb.active

for tup in p:
    sh.append(tup)

wb.save("output.xlsx")
wb.close()
```

Output :

[image]

Comment: Thank you.  It was tempting to think that a list of tuples would be an iterable too so that "append" would just simply default to appending each tuple on a row - kind of the same way Excel VBA does it with a range.